# Localization in C#

Tags: c#, string, localization, constants

Can I localize a a private const string?
Example:
I have a `Strings.resx` file, and in the file has a string call "Name". I can use it as `string name = Strings.Name;` however, can I assign "Name" to a private const string such as `private const string name = Strings.Name;`? I tried but failed, so I am wondering is possibly to do so? In other words, how can I localize a private const string?

In addition, can I add parameter to localization file?
Example:
If I want to create a message box with parameter such as `MessageBox.Show(user.name + " cannot be created for " + group.name + ". Already has same user name in the group.")` My solution now is create 2 strings in localization file `string1` contains `" cannot be created for "`, `string2` contains `". Already has same user name in the group."` I am wondering that is there any other simple way to do it?

Comment: As for number two: store it as a format and then call `string.Format`. e.g. `Strings.Message = "{0} cannot be created for {1}. Blabla`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but where should I put the formate? 'Strings.resx' or the 'MessageBox'? I tried put '{0} Cannot be created for {1}' in the 'Strings.resx' file and add to message box like 'MessageBox.Show(Strings.Name, user.name);' but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I localize a a private const string?

No,if it's localizable it's not constant...
What you can do is make the field readonly,then you can assign a value in the constructor or using a field initializer.

> Can I add parameter to localization file

Yes,you already know how to do that...
You just didn't use it correctly

The code sample below shows:
[image]
if you have a resource file
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly string aString = Strings.String1;
        public static void Main(string[] arccgs)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format(aString, "AAA", "BBB"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```